# Removing a word that contains specific word or part of the word from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string which I want to remove specific words that contains certain word inside of them.

for example: 
`String str = "Create_DateTime, Hello, DateTime, Before"`
each word that contains the word 'Date' should be removed so after the removal we will get the following string after the removal will be:
`Hello,Before`

I have this string:
`Expected_Start_DateTime,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,Start_DateTime,Instance_UID,Execution_Date,Metrics_Size_KB,End_DateTime,Tags_Countfrom command_execution`

and I've managed to remove all the unneeded words so now my string looks like that:
`,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,,Instance_UID,,Metrics_Size_KB,,Tags_Countfrom command_execution`

I want to remove the ',' before or after the word

This is the code I used to do the above:

`String str1 = str.replaceAll("\\w*Date\\w*","");`

Original string:
`Expected_Start_DateTime,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,Start_DateTime,Instance_UID,Execution_Date,Metrics_Size_KB,End_DateTime,Tags_Countfrom command_execution`

Expected:

`Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,,Instance_UID,Metrics_Size_KB,,Tags_Countfrom command_execution`

Actual:
`,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,,Instance_UID,,Metrics_Size_KB,,Tags_Countfrom command_execution`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be using java streams

```java
String str = "Expected_Start_DateTime,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,Start_DateTime,Instance_UID,Execution_Date,Metrics_Size_KB,End_DateTime,Tags_Countfrom command_execution";

String result = Stream.of(str.split(","))
                      .filter(word -> !word.contains("Date"))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you *really* want to do is work with arrays. (since you seem to be dealing with a string that is really a bunch of strings and commas). One way to accomplish what you want is to do str.split(",") and then loop through checking if strArray[i].contains("date"). let me know if I should be more clear

Comment: |Yep I can do it this way and it will be less expensive in manners of performance, but I'm really curious how it should be done using regex.

Comment: ```String str = "Expected_Start_DateTime,Metrics_Count,Device_UID,Command_Name,Command_Interval,Start_DateTime,Instance_UID,Execution_Date,Metrics_Size_KB,End_DateTime,Tags_Countfrom command_execution";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String st: str.split(",")){
            if(st.contains("Date")){
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(st+",");
        }```
But in the end I got unneeded "," at the end of the string builder.

Comment: @tupacshakur So, after all, you are not quite interested in a regex judging by the accepted answer. And it is good.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am still curious about how it being made using regex but of course, I would prefer the approach of which is less expensive.

Comment: @tupacshakur Arthur's answer is how it should be done, a single regex approach will look hacky and less readable, maintainable, etc.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew - I'm totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, an approach using arrays and `.split()` would probably be a better way to do this, but if you're curious about regex, here's a few you could use to accomplish your goal.

`\b\w*?[dD]ate\w*?\b` - this selects any word with "date" in it.

- The `\b` tag specifies a word boundary - if the character is not a word character (not a `\w`) it'll break, and will also break on the start and end of strings, so it'll catch your first and last words in the string too.
- The `\w` tag specifies a "word" character: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`. Since you don't have any weird characters in your words, this works quite well!
- `*?` matches as many word characters as it *needs,* but as few as it *can.*  This makes sure it catches all the characters before "Date", but only as many as are necessary for this word.
- `[dD]ate` looks literally for the words `date` or `Date`.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/7G7IAx/1/)

---

`^,*|,*$` - this selects the leading and trailing commas for you to dispose of.

- `^,*` - anchor the comma to the front of the string, and get as many as you can.
- `|` or...
- `,*$` - get as many commas as you can, anchored to the back of the string.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/7G7IAx/2/)

---

`,{2,}` - this selects all instances of 2 or more commas, for you to replace with a single comma.

- `,` select a comma, as long as...
- `{2,}` there are between 2 and unlimited numbers of them, next to each other.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/7G7IAx/3/)

---

Good luck!